# .net mvc view loop on javascript only updating first row in table

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have 2 rows in my loop.

I have 2 issues:

1. The JavaScript appears to be executing on each iteration; however, it is only populating the first table row data with the result.
2. I'm having to hard code the JSON object (for now) in the script, but ideally want to use a dynamic JSON string from my model data.  Though whenever I try to reference it (`@item.requestExample`), the JavaScript fails and the inspect/console in the browser shows that it is referencing the string and finding invalid tokens.  Instead of `"` it is finding `&quote;`. (I assume this is an HTML representation of the string?) How can I convert that to a true JavaScript object?  I've tried:

   ```
   var obj = JSON.parse('@(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@item.requestExample))');
   ```

   and

   ```
   var obj = dataString.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
   ```

   both with no luck because as soon as the `@item.requestExample` is referenced in the JavaScript, it is finds the invalid tokens and throws the flag.

Here is my complete loop in the mvc view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.list)
{
<tr class="table-info">
    <td>@item.library</td>
    <td>@item.api</td>
    <td>@item.ibmiPgm</td>
    <td> <pre id="uglyPretty"></pre> </td> 

    <script>

        var pretty = document.getElementById("uglyPretty");
        var obj = { "success": 1, "resultMessage": "Success", "list": [{ "custNo": "101", "firstName": "First Name: 101", "lastName": "Last Name: 101", "address1": "Address1: 101", "address2": "Address2: 101", "city": "City: 101", "state": "10", "zip": "101", "routing": "101", "accountNo": "101" }, { "custNo": "102", "firstName": "First Name: 102", "lastName": "Last Name: 102", "address1": "Address1: 102", "address2": "Address2: 102", "city": "City: 102", "state": "10", "zip": "102", "routing": "102", "accountNo": "102" }] };
        document.getElementById("uglyPretty").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);

    </script>

    <td>
        <button typeof="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(item.api, "", new { api = item.api, jsonRequest = item.requestExample } )'">Consume API</button>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: understood thanks Brian... what is the cleanest way to do that?

Comment: I mean I can easily implement a loop counter but the question is how getElementById is going to play with it.

Comment: Each "item" or each row/cell??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are just trying to display some JSON from your model item into a table cell, right?  And the issue is that the JSON is not formatted so you are trying to pretty-print it?
If that is the case, you are making this much harder than it needs to be.

Don't try to convert the JSON to a Javascript object just to reformat it; instead use a C# method to do the reformatting.  As your question is tagged with [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) I'm assuming you have [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) installed in your project.  If so, you can replace all that clumsy script code with this:

```
    <td>
        <pre>@Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(item.requestExample).ToString()</pre>
    </td>
```

So the full loop would look like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.list)
{
    <tr class="table-info">
        <td>@item.library</td>
        <td>@item.api</td>
        <td>@item.ibmiPgm</td>
        <td>
            <pre>@Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(item.requestExample).ToString()</pre>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button typeof="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(item.api, "", new { api = item.api, jsonRequest = item.requestExample } )'">Consume API</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: you summarized my objective exactly.  you provided the exact clean most non-invasive solution.  thank you!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.